# pthread_kill ends calling program

Tags: pthreads, kill

I am working on **Ubuntu** 12.04.2 LTS. I have a strange problem with `pthread_kill()`. The following program ends after writing only `"Create thread 0!"` to standard output. The program ends with exit status 138.

If I uncomment `"usleep(1000);"` everything executes properly. Why would this happen?

```cs
#include <nslib.h>

void *testthread(void *arg);

int main() {

    pthread_t tid[10];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("Create thread %d!\n", i);
        Pthread_create(&tid[i], testthread, NULL);
        //usleep(1000);
        Pthread_kill(tid[i], SIGUSR1);
        printf("Joining thread %d!\n", i);
        Pthread_join(tid[i]);
        printf("Joined %d!", i);
    }

    return 0;
}

void sighandlertest(int sig) {

    printf("print\n");
    pthread_exit();
    //return NULL;

}

void* testthread(void *arg) {

    struct sigaction saction;

    memset(&saction, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    saction.sa_handler = &sighandlertest;
    if(sigaction(SIGUSR1, &saction, NULL) != 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Sigaction failed!\n");
    }
    printf("Starting while...\n");
    while(true) {

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the main thread does not sleep a bit before raising the `SIGUSR1`, the signal handler for the thread created most propably had not been set up, so the default action for receiving the signal applies, which is ending the process.

Using `sleep()`s to synchronise threads is not recommended as not guaranteed to be reliable. Use other mechanics here. A condition/mutex pair would be suitable.

Declare a global state variable `int signalhandlersetup = 0`, protect access to it by a mutex, create the thread, make the main thread wait using `pthread_cond_wait()`, let the created thread set up the signal handle for `SIGUSR1`, set `signalhandlersetup = 0` and then signal the condition the main thread is waiting on using `pthread_signal_cond()`. Finally let the main thread call `pthread_kill()` as by your posting.